# How to fix ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, dll, module

I was trying to extract images from a video data source to create a deep face model, but I got the error below. How do I fix the error?

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\DeepFaceLab\core\leras\device.py", line 102, in _get_tf_devices_proc
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_DirectX12\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
  File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be an issue with how you have installed tensorflow in your system or the installed tensorflow version.
Please install tensorflow compatible to python 3.6 version as per this tested [build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) which is TensorFlow <=2.6.

You can [install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) specific tensorflow version using:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.6
```

**Note:** This is always recommended to use latest python and tensorflow version to take advantage of the latest features available for you.